# PHP rest API Routing path

Tags: php, rest, routes, kohana, kohana-3.3

I have a problem with routing. My routing path should looks like this `/foo/{ID}/path`. My first idea was to create new routing. But I am not sure about this solution. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `foo` is the controller and `path` is the action:

`Route::set('route name here', 'foo/<id>/path')
->defaults(
    array(
        'controller' => 'foo',
        'action'     => 'path',
    )
);`

Then `id` is available within the `path` action via:

`$id = $this->request->param('id');`

-edit-

You can also use something like this, if `id` has to satisfy certain requirements (exactly 8 characters long, and only a-z, A-Z and 0-9 in this example:

`Route::set('route name here', 'foo/<id>/path',
    array(
        'controller' => 'foo',
        'action'  => 'path',
        'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}',
    )
)
->defaults(
    array(
        'controller' => 'foo',
        'action'     => 'path',
    )
);`

-edit 2-

Sorry, just noticed you were asking for alternative solutions to creating a route for it, not *how* to create a route for it.

I'll leave this here though, as it might help someone else in the future.